# Scrolling effect on Android after embedding youtube videos with Iframe

Tags: android, html, iframe, mobile-website, embedding

I am making a slider with three different videos. I have some problems regarding the youtube videos embedding as if i embed the videos using **object** parameter, it works fine on each and every device except on MAC. I applied an alternative for this as i embedded the videos using **iframe**, now its fine everywhere but the problem occured is, the scrolling effect of the screen has stopped working on **Android** phones. I have tried applying js codes but still its stuck on Android. URL for my design is as follows if anybody wants to test the design on their end:

http://g-axon.com/minisite/

Please provide a proper solution  if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

Try not setting the divs with the class `oneByOne_item` to `display:none`.

Setting them to `display:none` will actually remove them from the render DOM.


And you dont need to that since the container is `overflow:hidden` anyway..